# vim + python buffer replacement using the "blackhole register"

Tags: python, vim

A simple python operation in vim scripting:

```
vim.current.buffer[current] = 'new line';
```

This overrides the current register, which I do not wish do to.

In other words, I want to replace the line with 'new line', but keep the contents of the register intact (the register is overwritten by this operation).

I am aware of the 'blackhole register' which seems relevant. But it isn't clear to me how to use it for buffer manipulation in scripting.

Comment: In your example, you try to replace the whole content of the buffer with "new line". If that's not what you want, can you explain what you want?

Comment: sorry, i meant 'register', updated accordingly

Comment: Could you explain what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Added another line. Basically the python operation is fine, I just don't want it to replace the register as a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this with Vim 7.3.823 on Windows/x64, and if the register were indeed modified, that would be a bug in Vim which should be reported on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php). Here's what I tried to reproduce:

```
:let @@ = 'foo'
:python import vim
:python vim.current.buffer[1] = 'new line'
:reg "
--- Registers ---
""   foo
```